# How can I tell LaTeX that an \input file is in a different encoding from inputenc?

Tags: unicode, r, input-encodings

I'm currently writing a .tex report with my wife. She's on a Windows machine and I'm running Linux over here; we've decided to encode our report in ISO-8859-1 (i.e., we use `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` on the preamble).

We're also generating lots of tables in R using `xtable()` and some other customized functions to output LaTeX. Whenever I sink an R output, I use this command: `sink(file("filename.tex", encoding = "ISO-8856-9"))`. There is, however, this one long table that contains lots of special characters. Whenever I try to sink this table as ISO I get this message:

```
Warning message:
invalid char string in output conversion
```

Even though it's just a warning, it prevents our LaTeX compiler from being able to correctly parse the command `\input{filename.tex}`.

The workaround we have for this is using `encoding = "UTF-8"` in R, then opening the file on a text editor and saving it with ISO encoding. Then LaTeX compiles the file correctly with apparently all special characters.

Is there a command by which I can tell LaTeX that a file I'm inputting has a different encoding from the main LaTeX file? In my mind, it would look something like this `\input[utf8]{filename.tex}` (but unfortunately `\input` or it's fellow `\include` don't take options).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you certain that the encoding should be ISO-8856-9? I've never heard of that one. Maybe you mean ISO-8859-6 (Arabic) or ISO-8859-9 (Turkish)?

Let's assume that you meant ISO-8859-9. Then you just write

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

in the beginning of your code,

```
\inputencoding{latin5}
```

just before you include the file and

```
\inputencoding{latin1}
```

to restore the original encoding.

EDIT:

UTF-8 might cause some problems. I'd solve it by stating that the whole document should be in UTF-8 and then switching back. Here's an example:

The following file is "main-file.tex", and should be saved with Latin 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{latin1}
\usepackage[russian,brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Nunca vi socó coçar sem bico, nunca vi sem bico socó coçar. Um socó, dois socós, três socós, quatro socós, quantos socós pra um só socó coçar.

\inputencoding{utf8}
\selectlanguage{russian}
\input{external-file}
\inputencoding{latin1}
\selectlanguage{brazil}

\section{Third section}
A sábia não sabia que o sábio sabia que o sabiá sabia que o sábio não sabia que o sabiá não sabia que a sábia não sabia que o sabiá sabia assobiar.
\end{document}
```

Also create the file "external-file.tex", and save it with UTF-8:

```
\section{Second section}
Карл у Клары украл кораллы, а Клара у Карла украла кларнет.
```

This works for me without any warnings at all. Let me know the specific warnings and errors if you still can't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that doesn't work (we're writing the document in Brazilian Portuguese, BTW, so we're using `\usepackage[brazil]{babel}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble. I've also tried ambracing my `\input{}` statement between `\inputencoding{utf8}` and `\inputencoding{latin1}`, but it didn't work.

Comment: @wleoncio It strange that it doesn't work, because it's working for me when I'm attempting a configuration that I believe is similar to yours. Could you try the example above and let me know if it works? Thanks.

Comment: That did work, no warnings or errors whatsoever. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If the only problem is in fact the warning message produced by the call to `sink(file())`, you could use `suppressWarnings()` to tell R that you don't want to hear any grumbling from that particular bit of code.

I can't exactly recreate your problem without the files you're working on, so here's an example that uses another `warning`-producing call. Here's how you could suppress the warning produced by an attempt to convert the character string "A" to a numeric vector:

```
sink(file("otherEgFile.txt", encoding = "ISO-8856-9"))    
suppressWarnings(as.numeric("A"))
sink()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. Maybe I'm doing this wrong, but when I use `supressWarnings()`, what it does is echo what should have been sunk.

Comment: @wleoncio Just to clarify, did you wrap the call that actually produces the warnings with `suppressWarnings()`? I realize I gave you the wrong advice, since the call to `sink()` is not where you are getting your warning. I'll edit my answer above accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Josh, your tip helped me solve the problem. What suppressing the warnings for the table inside the sink command actually did was generate a .tex file with an incomplete table. This table was interrupted just before the mischievous character. Since it only happens twice in the table, I can replace it inside the R script, before creating the table. BTW, here's the prick: ’

Comment: @wleoncio -- Superb. I'm glad to hear that helped you isolate the problem. Cheers.