# Can I make LuaLaTeX use \input files that are ANSI encoded?

Tags: luatex, unicode, input-encodings

I include/`\input` automatically generated files (tables generated by Stata) into my main document. I would like to compile that document with LuaLaTeX. Unfortunately the generated files are ANSI-encoded (Stata does not support unicode). LuaLaTeX thus throws a `"String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence"` error at me. At the moment, the problem is only a single character, namely ¤ (U00A4 according to Windows Character Map). With XeLaTeX or without the character the document compiles fine.

I would prefer to not search and replace the character (with e.g. \textcurrency, though something that works in math-mode as well would be preferred), since it involves many included files that change often. For the same reason I would prefer to not convert the encoding of the included files by hand. I would also prefer a more robust solution, i.e. not only for single characters.

So is there a way to make LuaLaTeX use included files that are ANSI encoded, comparable to [using \inputencoding with pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45448/)?

Alternatively, is it possible to automatically search and replace when compiling?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatextra, luaotfload}
\usepackage[vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math} % 
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic,Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures={TeX}} 
\setmainfont{Cambria}  
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} 

\begin{document}

A currency symbol in the main document: ¤ 

 \input{input.tex}

\end{document}
```

input.tex just has one line, but is ANSI-encoded.

```
A currency symbol in the included document: ¤
```

Comment: [(A slightly late) Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I suspect this may be a font-related problem, as I have managed to format an International Currency Symbol without the problem you mention.

Comment: Have you tried [luainputenc](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/luainputenc)?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: I added a MWE. The issue is not the currency symbol but the ANSI-encoded file. AFAIK LuaLaTeX only supports UTF-8 by default and the question basically is whether it is somehow possible to feed it an ANSI-encoded file nevertheless.

Comment: @Alexander: I tried it, but apparently I am not able to figure out how to use it properly.

Answer (score 6):

To tell LuaTeX to accept other encodings than UTF8 you need an additional package. Similar to the `inputenc` for LaTeX `luainputenc` provides the necessary commands for LuaTeX. The basic syntax is just `\usepackage[<encoding>]{luainputenc}`. Where the most commonly used encodings are latin1 and cp1252. The slightly changed example compiles without errors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{luainputenc}

\usepackage{luatextra, luaotfload}
\usepackage[vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math} % 
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic,Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures={TeX}} 
\setmainfont{Cambria}  
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} 

\begin{document}

A currency symbol in the main document: ¤ 

\input{input.tex}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively you could use tools such as [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) to automatically convert the file.

Comment: Hm, simple. Makes me wonder why I did not try the [latin1] option. Anyway, two questions: First, I would like to only encode the included files as latin1, so what's the equivalent to \inputencoding (cf. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45448/))? Second, if I want to be able to compile the document with xelatex or pdflatex (via ifxetex/ifluatex), how should I setup the document (also in combination with Q1)? I.e. is luainputenc compatible with xelatex/pdflatex?

Comment: @dapperdan: \inputencoding should also work in luainputenc. I think it is also compatible with xelatex/pdflatex by simply calling inputenc instead.

Comment: Well, if I change `\usepackage[latin1]{luainputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` and insert `\inputencoding{cp1252}` before `\input{input.tex}` I still get a `String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.` error for the included document. (Again note the different encodings of the two documents.)

Comment: @dapperdan: `\inputencoding` switches the encoding mid-document but somehow not completely. As this is a workaround anyway I would suggest using a batch file to automatically convert the input document instead.